# What's the difference between Drop and Remove in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I see there's two ways to remove collections in Mongodb. I just want to delete it essentially.

Should I use:

```
db.collection.drop()
```

Or

```
db.collection.remove()
```

Comment: Have you tried reading documentation on those methods? One of them doesn't delete the collection.

Comment: @Stennie it's not the same question. I'm talking about removing an entire collection, not removing the documents one by one.

Comment: @foreyez The duplicate answer explains what the two options do: `drop()` completely deletes the collection; `remove({})` deletes matching documents while preserving (and updating) indexes. If your intent is to delete a collection, you should use `drop()`.

Comment: @Stennie although the answer is the same, the question is not the same, and it should not be marked as duplicated.

Comment: `DeprecationWarning: remove is deprecated. Use delete_one or delete_many instead.`

Answer (score 14):

Once we have documents stored in our collection , we can remove all of the documents from it in two ways. Now choosing one over another is totally depends on your requirement.

**1. [Using drop():](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.drop/)**
By invoking `drop()` on a collection , it will remove all the documents from it ,it will delete all the indexes on it  and at the end it will delete the collection itself.

**2.[Using remove():](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/)** 
 remove has two overloaded versions ,one in which we will pass the criteria to remove all the documents that are matching our passed criteria and 2nd one is default where we won’t pass any criteria (prior to 2.6) or pass an empty document (version 2.6 or more) and it will remove all the documents from the collection. Here, we are more interested in 2nd version when our intention is to clear all the documents from a collection.

**Remark:** *To remove all documents from a collection, it may be more efficient to use the `drop()` method to drop the entire collection, including the indexes, and then recreate the collection and rebuild the indexes.*

Comment: what does it mean to 'remove all indexes'

Comment: Indexes are special data structures that store a small portion of the collection’s data set in an easy to traverse form. Indexes support the efficient execution of queries in MongoDB. Without indexes, MongoDB must perform a collection scan, i.e. scan every document in a collection, to select those documents that match the query statement. If an appropriate index exists for a query, MongoDB can use the index to limit the number of documents it must inspect. You can find more details here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Answer (score 5):

Based on the documentation, `remove()`

> Removes documents from a collection.

but doesn't get rid of the collection (or associated indexes).  `remove()` can take parameters to specify deletion criteria as well.

`drop()` gets rid of the collection and associated indexes:

> Removes a collection or view from the database. The method also removes any indexes associated with the dropped collection. The method provides a wrapper around the drop command.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/

It's a little bit like the difference between `DELETE` (or *maybe* `TRUNCATE`) and `DROP TABLE/VIEW` in relational SQL.

Comment: but I removed an entire collection using the remove() command.. maybe the only difference is remove just has criteria and drop doesn't or something

Comment: Are you sure it actually removed the collection and not just all the documents in the collection?  Did you have indexes on the collection?

Comment: not sure what means to remove "indexes" on a collection.. what indexes

Comment: Any indexes you created on that collection.  Which I guess means you didn't have any :)